# Is it OK to ask questions about CDN at stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

I've seen some questions about CDN, how to use it, how to build it, or even suggesting best practices for CDN's URL patterns.

Examples are:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101814/best-practice-for-url-pattern-to-use-in-cdn-and-its-contents
[CDN and URL's with query-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330011/cdn-and-urls-with-query-strings)
[What are CDN Best Practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704490/what-are-cdn-best-practices)

Are they on-topic here? If not, to which other StackExchange site should we guide users?

Comment: Two of them are very old. All three questions are fairly different from each other. The new one may or may not be a viable question, but it's not *terrible*. One has the dreaded "best practices" in the title, but I feel kind of "meh" about all this. Is there a specific reason for your interest in these questions?

Comment: @probablyPekka, thanks for your feedback. Yeah, I have a special reason for this, because the fellow how has asked this question is a colleague of mine, and we do have a problem deciding a good pattern for URLs. I thought "after all, it's a development question, and it's too technical to be asked on programmers. Also, it's not subjective, so it could have a definite answer". So I encouraged him to ask it on SO. But somebody has voted to close. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: I see. The votes aren't there because of the topic of CDNs, though - they're because 2 people think question is "primarily opinion-based". Which arguably is true. That said, what do you need a URL pattern for in the first place? I'm lost as to why someone would need that. Why break up packages that make logical sense, and file them by MIME type?

Comment: Oh, we didn't mean to make it opinion-based. But, what if we don't do that in URL? can we simply go like `http://cdn/jquery.js`? Because it's usually a static resource, we want IIS to deliver it. Thus it's important that we have a good file-system architecture, because URL path maps directly to physical path on the hard.

Comment: Well, any answer is going to be opinion based, as this is an architectural choice. You could take a look at how other sites do it, e.g. Stack Overflow: they separate by site name and resource type (`/stackoverflow/img/xyz`). Other sites just use `http://cdn/323131423423423.css`.